# If no value in textbox return String Java

Tags: java, string, return, compare

I have to compare if a String is in a textbox inserted, if not it should return a String. It does not work with this line of code below, has somebody an idea?

```
if (inString.trim().length() == 0) 
            return "b";
```

Here is the whole block of Code:

```
public static String checkYear(String inYear) {


      // Gets the current date and time.
    // Returns the actual year as an int.
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();   // Gets the current date and time.
    int currYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   try
  {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(inYear);

        if (inYear.trim().length() == 0) 
                 return "b";


            if ((year >= 1900) && (year <= currYear)) 
            return ""; //valid date
            else
            return "Year must be between 1900 and current year";

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Year must be a Number";
    }

}
```

I've get an exception.

I test if nothing is inside the text block with this Code:

```
    String year = txtYear.getText();
    String msgYear = DVD.checkYear(year); 
    int year2 = 0;

if (msgYear.length() == 1 )
          {
              year2 = 0;

          DVD dvd2 = new DVD(txtTitle.getText(),
                           year2,
                       favouriteCheck);
           dvdCollect.addDVD(dvd2);                
           parent.refreshDVDList();
          }
```

Comment: Please provide more code and a complete description of what you wish to accomplish so  that your problem can be adequately assessed and resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
if (inYear.trim().length() == 0) 
             return "b";`
```

makes no sense after the line

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(inYear);
```

If `inYear` consists of nothing but white space, `Integer.parseInt` will already have thrown a `NumberFormatException` and the exception caught.

The code

```
if (inString == null || inString.trim().isEmpty())
    return "b";
```

should go before the `try` block.

Comment: This answer checks out. As a side note, `inString.trim().length() == 0` would be better as `inString.trim().isEmpty()`.

Comment: @dohaqatar7 I agree. Edit made.

Comment: Thank you now I don't get an Exception when I do not enter anything but it still does not save the data. My question now is: It returns now a String with the length of 1 right? I compare it like that:  if (msgYear.length() == 1 )

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to save the data. I'd ask it as a separate question (after accepting my answer to this one of course!).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `inString` will hold the String entered in text box, I believe it should be:

```
if (inString ==null || (inString!=null && inString.trim().length() ==0))
    return "b"
```